# Thumb ring and index finger

Tags: handlebars, health, brake-levers

I have a new bike for 3 month and after about 20 Km my ring and index finger on the left hand became numb. Just as an information for my hand position: These fingers are always on the brakes. Here is my handlebar and brake lever position. Any idea how to adjust them to get rid of this problem?

[image]
[image]

Comment: "These fingers are always on the brakes."  That's your problem.  You've got to move your hands around.

Comment: Personally I prefer the trailling bulge of the grip to be a lot higher, to provide palm support.  But with those ones the barend might be integrated so raising one lowers the other ?

Comment: Silly clarification - from stem outwards, my digits are thumb, index finger, middle (long) finger, ring finger, little finger.   Do you really have your index and ring finger on the brake and your middle/long finger around the handlebar?  That sounds horrible!   Try with just your index finger on the brake levers, or maybe index and middle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing obviously wrong with your handlebar setup. As long the shift and brake levers are easily accessible and you don't have to rotate your wrists or shift your hand laterally along the bar to reach them everything is OK

*Maybe* I'd consider moving the levers slightly outwards (and I note there is a slight difference in position, the right hand one is slightly more inboard.

Numb hands are a common problem. You don't have to ride with your fingers on the levers all the time. Try moving you hands around the bars and bar ends and flexing your fingers from time to time.

Comment: To add to this, use your bar end grips. Also, make sure your bar and front wheel are aligned; small adjustment problems can translate into big discomfort over long rides.